# Are there any states of the review iOS review process where you can not reject the binary?

Tags: ios

I want to know what states I can reject the binary so I can understand the risk of the app being locked in the review process, preventing a new app from being submitted. [From the guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html):

- **Upload Received** - From my experience the reject options is not available, however it usually moves to the next state within a few mins.
- **Waiting For Review** - You can reject the binary in this state. I have done this before and it says so in the docs.
- **In Review** - Docs suggest you can reject the binary in this state, but someone in my team seems to think its not possible.  I have never done it so I am not sure.
- **Pending Contract** - No idea - It does not say anything in the docs.
- **Waiting For Export Compliance** - No idea - It does not say anything in the docs.
- **Pending Developer Release** - Can reject in this state - I have done it before.

So the ones I am not sure about are: `In Review`, `Pending Contract` and `Waiting For Export Compliance` Can I reject the binary from these states?

Comment: Not 100% sure but if it was a case where you wanted to withdraw it you can unselect all options in the 'available territories' (or countries) and that would withdraw a live app from all iTunes stores ... Then just submit an update to replace the accepted binary.

Comment: @CW0007007 - Ah thanks - thats useful to know.  Was that just when the app was in the 'Ready for Sale' state?

Comment: in my experience you can reject also when in review

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reject the binary in the `Under Review` state the first time you are uploading the app to iTunes Connect.  Once your app is accepted and a version is established for your app on iTunes Connect, then you'll have the option to reject the binary in the `Under Review` state for future version uploads.

The `Pending Contract` and `Waiting For Export Compliance` states mean you haven't completed all the necessary documents in the  `Contracts, Tax and Banking` section of iTunes Connect. As long as your app is in either or both of these states, it cannot be accepted by Apple. The ability to reject the binary depends entirely on whether or not the app is being uploaded for the first time..

Comment: Ah ok this might explain why my colleague seems to think you could not reject a binary while it was in review.  Is there any documentation that says you can not reject on the initial submit?

Comment: Here's the official Apple documentation on rejecting a binary (https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/submission/tips.html, in the "Changing the Status of Your App" section), but there's nothing there about first-time submittal.  I think I read it in an Apple Developer forum answer.